# How to raise Exception in OPENSOCKETFUNCTION of pycurl

Tags: python, libcurl, pycurl

As per https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_OPENSOCKETFUNCTION.html,
libcurl document said that this callback can be used for IP address blacklisting, so I decided to use it to block all private IP address.

I have tried `raise Exception` directly in my custom callback function, but it won't propagate any exception to `curl.perform` except timeout occurred.

Is it possible to catch the exception I raised in callback function from `curl.perform()` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible for pycurl to propagate Python exceptions in callbacks out of `perform` calls, however this is not currently implemented. Right now each callback should return an appropriate value to indicate the error; in case of opensocket callback, this value is CURL_SOCKET_BAD. (Unfortunately, pycurl does currently not expose this constant either; use `-1` instead.)

One way to provide rich error information is to store it on the Curl object itself, as follows:

```
import pycurl, random, socket

class ConnectionRejected(Exception): pass

def opensocket(curl, purpose, curl_address):
    if random.random() < 0.5:
        curl.exception = ConnectionRejected('Rejecting connection attempt in opensocket callback')
        # should be pycurl.SOCKET_BAD in the next release
        return -1

    family, socktype, protocol, address = curl_address
    s = socket.socket(family, socktype, protocol)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1)
    return s

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://pycurl.io')
c.exception = None
c.setopt(c.OPENSOCKETFUNCTION,
    lambda purpose, address: opensocket(c, purpose, address))
try:
    c.perform()
except pycurl.error as e:
    if e.args[0] == pycurl.E_COULDNT_CONNECT and c.exception:
        print(c.exception)
    else:
        print(e)
```

Additionally pycurl doesn't currently handle -1/CURL_SOCKET_BAD return quite correctly - it complains that -1 is not a valid return value (but functionality is not otherwise affected). https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl/pull/484 will repair this.

Answer (score 0):

The callback functions are pure C functions, there are no exceptions in C. A plain C library, and it doesn't know anything about exceptions.

You can find the details here goo.gl/SLrKCF